Why do we need quaternions when we already have continuous mappings $\mathbb{R}^3\to SO(3)$?
Forgive me for asking such a basic question. What are the advantages of using quaternions over the following continuous mapping $\mathbb{R}^3\to SO(3)$?

The mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to SO(3):v\mapsto e^{[v\times]}$. This can alternatively be written $f:v\mapsto\cos(|v|)I+\text{sinc}(\left|v\right|)[v\times]+\frac12\text{sinc}\left(\frac12|v|\right)vv^\top$, where $I$ is the $3\times3$ identity matrix and $[v\times]$ represents the cross product matrix of $v$, i.e. the skew symmetric matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&-v\cdot k&v\cdot j\\v\cdot k&0&-v\cdot i\\-v\cdot j&v\cdot i&0\end{bmatrix}$, where $i$, $j$, and $k$ are the unit vectors.

The above mapping $f$ gives the axis-angle representation of a rotation matrix; the length $|v|$ of $v$ is the amount of rotation (counterclockwise in radians) and the direction of $v$ represents the axis of rotation of the rotation you want to create.
As far as I'm aware this avoids gimbal lock and other associated issues with rotation, and feels more intuitive than quaternions to me. Also rotations in 3D have three degrees of freedom, and quaternions having more makes them feel like less of an advantage compared to this. Why don't we use this instead?

Clarification: $\text{sinc}(x)$ here denotes $\frac{\sin x}x$ with the hole filled at $x=0$ to become nice and analytic.


It depends what problem you are trying to solve. If you are only interested in unit quaternions, then maybe you are right (although I find the formulas for quaternion multiplication much more straightforward and memorable than your matrix formula). If you are interested in rings and how the process of adding roots of $-1$ works (Dickson doubling), then the quaternions are natural, utterly fascinating and lead in lots of interesting new directions. See Conway and Smith's beautiful book "On Quaternions and Octonions" for a starter. PS: what's "sinc"?

A quaternion has $4$ components. Your matrix exponential has $9$ components. It's easier to store quaternions than matrices.
It's also easier to multiply two quaternions than two matrices. The former requires $16$ multiplications of real numbers, and the latter $27$.
On the other hand, it's harder to multiply a vector by two quaternions in the "sandwich product", than by a matrix. The former requires $24$ multiplications of real numbers, and the latter $9$.
So matrices are better if you want to apply a single rotation to many vectors. Quaternions are better if you want to compose many rotations.
If you only store the $3$ components of the vector $v$, then you can take the quaternion exponential as well as the matrix exponential. But what do you do to compose two rotations? How do you combine two axis-angle vectors to get a third?

The mapping $f$ in the original question has some problems. One is that computers and some programs (e.g. Mathematica) can struggle to do stuff properly with $\text{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. The division by $0$ at $x=0$ in sinc and its derivatives is ugly. But why did this happen?
Let $\theta$ be an angle and $u$ be a unit vector. The rotation matrix $R$ for rotating points in space by an angle of $\theta$ around $u$ is $R=I+\sin(\theta)[u\times]+2\sin^2\left(\frac\theta2\right)[u\times]^2$. One temptation is to describe rotations with four numbers $(\theta,u_x,u_y,u_z)$, but the problem with this is that $u$ is undefined for $\theta=0$. Any direction, $u$, appears to work - and you will be tempted to define a different value of $u$ at $\theta=0$ depending on how you approach it; the limit does not even exist, and no choice of $u$ in $\mathbb{R}$ will make this mapping from $\mathbb{R}^4\to SO(3)$ continuous. Thus, instead of making the $u$ term "jump", as $\theta$ approaches zero we want its magnitude to steadily shrink towards the origin. The natural choice is just to multiply $\theta$ and $u$ to get the vector $\theta u$ which can roam freely through 3D space, compactly describes a rotation, and maps continuously into $SO(3)$. However, as stated, in multiplying $u$ by $\theta$ in one place, we had to divide by it somewhere else. This introduces the sinc function and some associated problems.
On the other hand, the term $\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)u$ sitting right there in the expression is already going to zero, so why do more than you need to? This introduces a new variable $v=\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)u$, and then you have to do some shuffling ($\sin(\theta)=2\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)$) to fully introduce the change:
$R=I+2\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)[v\times]+2[v\times]^2$.
This leftover term $\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)$ is kinda ugly. However, we could call it its own variable $s$. It is not cleanly reducible to a quantity derived from $v$ because $|v|$ only tells you what $\left|\sin\frac\theta2\right|$ is. Thus by taking the lazy approach and calling $\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)$ $s$, we've created a lazy way to describe rotations in 3D space that avoids division by zero; we use the four parameters $(s,v_x,v_y,v_z)$ which must satisfy $s^2+v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2=1$. Incidentally the quadruple $(s,v_x,v_y,v_z)$ describes exactly the unit quaternion $s+v_xi+v_yj+v_zk$ of the corresponding rotation. Thus, the function I laid out in my question was flawed because it was too close to dividing by zero, and an attempt to fix this leads directly to the invention of quaternions.
I can also answer this with a meme:

Hope this helps anyone who has the same question about the mapping I had in my problem.
